# Is it possible to determine lat/lon from an arbitrary google maps url?

Tags: google-maps, location

Is it possible to determine a latitude and longitude from an arbitrary Google Maps url that doesn't include a latlng param? For example, the following maps url

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=sutro+baths&hl=en&fb=1&gl=us&hq=sutro+baths&hnear=0x80859a6d00690021:0x4a501367f076adff,San+Francisco,+CA&cid=0,0,16148491297203403134&t=v&z=16&iwloc=A

Secondary, perhaps related question: In that url what do the two colon delimited hex numbers in the hnear param encode?

...&hnear=**0x80859a6d00690021:0x4a501367f076adff**,San+Francisco,+CA&...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the url like this:

```
    http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:38.9419+-78.3020
```

I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon) is the answer you desire

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some work to do, but a related answer here explains where to look in the response of the link(s) for a pattern to get the lat/lon.

> The position information is written somewhere in the javascript code
>   inside the html. You can find the pattern
>   "viewport:{center:{lat:xxx,lng:xxx}}" in the javascript code.

[How to Obtain Lat/Lng of Google Maps Query String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940131/how-to-obtain-lat-lng-of-google-maps-query-string)

Edit: For example, view source of your map page and search for viewport:
viewport_center_lat=37.779850006103516;var viewport_center_lng=-122.51384735107422;